# An honorarium including flight and hotel will be included

Tags: meaning

I was invited to a meeting saying: "An honorarium including flight and hotel will be included."

Does this mean that the honorarium includes travel + hotel or travel + hotel + honorarium for the lecture?

Comment: How does it make a difference? You get an honorarium that also takes care of travel and stay.

Comment: ...but not for the invited talk?

Comment: @Kris I guess the question is whether hotel and travel should be deducted from the mentioned amount or not. This may make a considerable difference when considering accepting the offer.

Comment: You may wish to ask for clarification from the organizers, because the sentence is poorly worded and ambiguous. The intended meaning may be "An honorarium intended to cover the cost of your flight and hotel stay will be included." That is, they have already estimated the amounts (perhaps overestimated them) and will pay you that much. An alternative meaning is "An honorarium will be included, and we will also reimburse the cost of your flight and hotel stay." This meaning seems less likely but still possible.